# Create a complete backup of the Whatsapp "Media" folder by deleteing all the .nomedia files in all the subfolders

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

WhatsApp stores all ***sent*** and ***received*** **images**, **documents**, and **videos** in the following file structure:

Internal memory >> Android >> Media >> com.whatsapp >> Whatsapp >> **Media** ------ **(A)**

This **Media** folder has folders named

- WhatsApp Audio
- WhatsApp Documents
- WhatsApp Images
- WhatsApp Video
- WhatsApp Voice Notes

Now, each of the above five folders has two sub-folders:

- Private
- Sent

These two sub-folders have **.nomedia** files inside them.

I have manually deleted all the .nomedia files from all these sub-folders and sub-sub-folders before backing up the chats using Chat backup in WhatsApp settings. However, these .nomedia files are getting re-created every time I tap "Back up now".

---

To go into a little more detail as to the **steps** I have followed, they are, in chronological order:

1. Clear all apps from my Android phone RAM (OnePlus 7 Pro).
2. Open app WhatsApp.
3. Go to Settings >> Chats >> Chat backup (but do not tap anything).
4. Tap the center circle (Home button) so that WhatsApp is **not exited in the usual manner**.
5. Open file explorer app Solid Explorer and go to the Whatsapp **Media** location mentioned in **(A)** above.
6. Delete all the .nomedia files in all the folders, sub-folders and sub-sub-folders inside this location.
7. Tap the center circle (Home button) so that Solid Explorer is not exited in the usual manner.
8. Tap the recent apps button and go to WhatsApp. Now, I am on the same screen on WhatsApp as I had left it in Step 4 above (Settings >> Chats >> Chat backup screen).
9. Tap "Back up now"
10. Wait on the same screen till the backup is complete.

---

After following the above steps, I see that .nomedia files have been created inside all the folders that I had deleted them from, with the timestamp on each equal to the exact time when I tapped "Back up now" in Step 9 above.

This would mean that the data in the Private and Sent folders inside each of WhatsApp Audio, WhatsApp Documents, etc. have not been backed up.

Can anyone suggest a way so that the data inside those folders are also backed up?

Or, if possible, share a different method so that I can have the data inside those folders in my backup?